# Longest Path in a Directed Graph with Specified Number of Edges

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G$ be a directed graph that has $n$ nodes and is strongly connected. Define a random path as the following: Pick two vertices uniformly at random and find the shortest path going from one vertex to another (either way is fine). Can we bound the length of a random path of $G$ if we know the size of $|E|$?

For example, if $E = O(n)$, then it seems easy to construct a graph with only large paths. However, if $E = \Theta(n^2)$, then it is likely that the graph has short expected path size. What if $|E| = o(n^2)$ or $O(n \log n)$ ? Can we derive any bounds for the expected length of a random path in these cases? What if our graph is undirected?

Comment: I guess that all edges have equal length?

Comment: What do you mean by random path?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I have edited to make this more clear

Answer (score 1):

Even if $E$ grows as $cn^2$, the random path may have length about $n$. Consider a complete graph on $n/2$ vertices joined with a path of length $n/2$.